# Which steps are needed to implement a custom Authentication & Authorization scheme in Blazor Server on Linux for Active Directory/LDAP access?

Tags: c#, ldap, blazor, blazor-server-side

We develop an Application using .NET Core 3.1.X with Blazor Server to run on Linux.

Our requirement is to authenticate against a local Active Directory server (using LDAP).
Reading the documentation we've learned that a component called [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) is responsible for the authentication and that doesn't seem to support non-Azure Active Directory or generic LDAP.

Additionally, it seems as if the `DirectoryServices` are not yet available on Linux.

I did not find any documentation that lays out all steps needed to get our desired authentication scheme working. So: Which steps do we need to take to reach "feature parity" with the built-in authentication & authorization schemes.

As this seems like a very obvious use-case (Active Directory & LDAP) to me I'm also wondering if we missed anything obvious during our research.

Comment: Although this is a worthy question, its a little too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to make it more specific? I'm happy to edit the question.

Comment: One advice for free. If you can, don't use ASP.NET Identity at all. I've suffered all it's infamous versions and they're nasty... You'll end tangled up on a miriad of interfaces, overridings and changing conventions. Try for yourself, it's not that difficult. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I haven't touched C# etc. in 15 or so years so any advice is welcome.